# Storing Sessions in MongoDB with Silex

Tags: php, mongodb, session, silex

I use silex with doctrine/mongodb (+fate/Silex-Extensions) and now I want to store sessions with this combination. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. But you might be better off using something like memcached instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, all you need to do is write an implementation of the [SessionHandler](http://php.net/sessionhandler). You can look at the implementations present in Symfony, for example the [MemcacheSessionHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/MemcacheSessionHandler.php).

You can then override the `SessionServiceProvider`'s `session.storage.handler` service to your own implementation:

```
$app['session.storage.handler'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new Your\MongoDBSessionHandler();
});
```

PS: It may indeed be easier to use something like redis or memcache, because their extensions already ship with pre-defined session handlers that you can use. You can simply [disable the default session handler](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/session.html#custom-session-configurations) in silex in order to get it to use the global php.ini configuration.

Comment: Thanks! According to your link, I found a ready solution: [MongoDbSessionHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/MongoDbSessionHandler.php)